# Gradle renaming file name with wildcards

Tags: file, gradle, zip

I have the following task in my `build.gradle`

task zipConfiguration(type: Zip) {
def myDir = project(':SomeProject').projectDir.toString() + '/build/libs/'
from myDir
archiveName 'Output.zip'
destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/libs")
}

`build/libs` of project `SomeProject` will always have one versioned jar file. For e.g. `configuration_2021_06.jar`

With every build, the jar created will have a new version number. So the name of the jar I am zipping is dynamic.

However, I want a constant name `myconfig.jar` to go inside the `Output.zip`

How can I rename `configuration_*.jar` to `myconfig.jar` ?

Tried `rename ('*.jar', 'myconfig.jar')` : Gives error `Dangling meta character '*' near index 0`

Tried `rename ('configuration*.jar', 'myconfig.jar')` : Doesn't rename it. I still see
`configuration_2021_06.jar` inside `Output.zip`

Answer (score 1):

The `*` needs to be like:

```
 rename ('configuration(.*).jar', 'myconfig.jar')
```